# XCTAsssertEqual failed on UTTest

Tags: swift2, xctest, xcode-ui-testing, xcode7.3

I am new in writing tests. I tried to write a test for a button tapped with title "0" and after tapped its title must change to "1". Test function is below:

```
func testTapNumberButtonIncrementsScore() {
    XCUIApplication().buttons["0"].tap()
    let newScore = XCUIApplication().buttons["1"].label
    XCTAssertEqual(newScore, "1")
}
```

on line with 'newScore' I get error stating "UI Testing Failure - No matches found for "1" Button"

It seems title of button isn't changed on tap. I have changed button's title when button is tapped in @IBAction of this button. However, if I keep breakpoint in the line with 'newScore' and wait for sometime and continue; the test successes.

Answer (score 2):

You have to wait of the button with the label "1".

```
XCUIApplication().buttons["0"].tap()
let newScoreButton = XCUIApplication().buttons["1"]
let exists = NSPredicate(format: "exists == 1 || enabled == 1")
expectation(for: exists, evaluatedWith: newScoreButton, handler: nil)
waitForExpectations(timeout: 50) { error in
     if error != nil {
            assertionFailure("The newScoreButton doesn't exists.")
     }
}
newScore = newScoreButton.label
XCTAssertEqual(newScore, "1")
```